# Razor Syntax prevent space after razor code snippet

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im trying to get this as the result javascript:

```
var targetChart = mymodel_chart;
```

from this:

```
var targetChart = @Model.visualChartName/*dont know what to do here*/_chart;
```

But theres always a whitespace rendered in between the two statements on the right side, like this:

```
var targetChart = mymodel _chart;
```

How can I prevent this whitespace to be written there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various solutions, if I understand correctly, this can be one:

```
var targetChart = @(Model.visualChartName+"_chart"); //based that visualChartName is a string
```